# You're given $51$ natural numbers between $[1,100]$. Show that there are two of these numbers whose sum is $101$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, pigeonhole-principle

> You're given $51$ natural numbers between $[1,100]$. Show that there are two of these numbers whose sum is $101$.

This seems to be an application of the pigeonhole principle? I started considering different sets as the boxes, but this didn't quite lead anywhere. How should I approach this kind of problem?

Comment: There are precisely $50$ pairs which sum up to $101$, being $1+100, 2+99,3+98,\ldots, 50+51$. This is a good place to start!

Comment: Probably $51$ _distinct_ natural numbers.

Comment: @EBP So I have $50$ pigeonholes and $51$ pigeons?

Comment: Yes.  The fact that the pigeonholes happen to have maximum size $2$ is somewhat interesting but largely irrelevant for the punchline of this particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider pairs $(1,100),(2,99),\cdots ,(50,51).$

Comment: I see, these are my boxes and I would have to count how many of them there are?

Comment: You then have to put $0$ or $1$ in each box, so can place at most $50$ so can't place $51.%$

Comment: In my last comment, the reason $0$ or $1$ in each is to avoid a sum of $101$ in one or more boxes. (It's a proof by contradiction in a way.)